# How do you mount sub-directories from a named docker volume in a container?

Tags: docker, storage

I know that you cannot directly mount a sub-directory from a named volume, but there must be a pattern to accomplish this task (I would assume).

The scenario is that I have a named volume (via `convoy-nfs`) that contains some shared data that is to be mounted *readonly* by multiple containers on the host.

The only way I can see this working is to run multiple *setup* commands to symlink each sub-directory (or file) from the mounted named volume into the target location. This doesn't feel like the right answer, as it requires much more customization to the run command than I would like.

Is there a better method?

Comment: From the name `convoy-nfs` I assume that it's an nfs mount. Do you mount it on the host yourself (bash scripts) or do you use a docker nfs driver like [netshare](http://netshare.containx.io/docs/nfs) ?

Comment: `convoy-nfs` is handling the mounting transparently by acting as a docker volume plugin. so the docker container simply binds a named volume and the plugin persists the data in an nfs mount.

Comment: You should be able to create local volumes from your nfs mounted drive. Eg: `-v /mnt/nfs-mount-root/subdir1:/suddir1`, `-v /mnt/nfs-mount-root/suddir2:/subdir2`. Use `docker volume inspect convoy-nfs` to find the mount point on your host.

Comment: i think that would defeat the purpose of using `convoy-nfs` as a storage abstraction layer.

Comment: I spent all day trying to get to the bottom of this and as far as I can tell when using an abstraction layer you should always be mounting every volume from its own dedicated store. Turns out that `convoy-nfs` is quite buggy so I have transitioned to using single use containers to mount NFS exports on the host, which I can then remount sub-directories as shared volumes in my containers.

Comment: yes mounting on the host and then "partitioning" subdirs into docker volumes seems to be the only way.